# Escaping jQuery data being sent via POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I'm using jQuery.ajax to extract form data from a page, and send it to my database (via another PHP page).

The form information is collected by:

```
var X=$('#div1').val();
var Y=$('#div2').val();
```

This is used to build the POST string, i.e.

```
var data='varx='+X+'&vary='+Y;
```

Obviously this is problematic if an ampersand character is used. What is the best method to escape the variables, particularly so that the user can safely use an ampersand (&) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best would be using an object for the data.

```
jQuery.post("yourScript.php", {
   varx: X,
   vary: Y
});
```

or

```
jQuery.ajax({
      url: "yourScript.php",         
      type: "POST",
      data: ({varx: X, vary: Y}),
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(msg){
         alert(msg);
      }
   }
);
```

You can also use jQuery's serialize() to get your form data as a serialized querystring:

```
var data = jQuery(formSelector).serialize();
```

> The .serialize() method creates a text
>   string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It operates on a jQuery
>   object representing a set of form
>   elements. The form elements can be of
>   several types.

Way prettier in my opinion :-)

Answer (score 26):

[`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) will do what you are looking for.

```
var X = encodeURIComponent($('#div1').val());
var Y = encodeURIComponent($('#div2').val());
```

This will encode all potentially insecure characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use escape function of JavaScript

```
var data='varx='+escape(X)+'&vary='+escape(Y);
```

Comment: The escape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() instead.