# Having problems submitting form without page refresh using AJAX and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting the success alert which shows this datastring, but for some reason my php code is not executing or else it is truly not successful, I'm unsure of which. Thanks.

```
inputPlantSite=Syncrude+Base+Mine&inputRouteNumber=aafdfadsfadsafds&inputStopNumber=asfdafdsasfdafds&inputLatitude=57.90609313959766&inputLongitude=-113.4063720703125&inputStreetName=asfdafdsasfdafds&inputArrivalTime=asfdafdsasfdafds&inputDayOfWeek=Weekday&inputDirectionOfBus=Town+to+Site&inputWhatShift=asfdafdsasfdafds&markerVariable=addmarker
```

Here is my Ajax/Jquery

```
 $(function() {
  $("#submit_marker").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
    var inputPlantSite = $("#inputPlantSite").val();
    var inputRouteNumber = $("#inputRouteNumber").val();
    var inputStopNumber = $("#inputStopNumber").val();
    var inputLatitude = $("#inputLatitude").val();
    var inputLongitude = $("#inputLongitude").val();
    var inputStreetName = $("#inputStreetName").val();
    var inputArrivalTime = $("#inputArrivalTime").val();
    var inputDayOfWeek = $("#inputDayOfWeek").val();
    var inputDirectionOfBus = $("#inputDirectionOfBus").val();
    var inputWhatShift = $("#inputWhatShift").val();
    var inputAddMarker = $("#inputAddMarker").val();
    var inputUpdateMarker = $("#inputUpdateMarker").val();
    var inputDeleteMarker = $("#inputDeleteMarker").val();
    var dataString = $('#formManageMarker').serialize();
    alert(dataString);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "php/addmarker.php",
      data: dataString,
dataType: "json",
      success: function() {
        alert("Successfully added marker");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

and here is my form:

```
    <form name="formManageMarker" method="post" action="">
      <select name="inputPlantSite" class="input-block-level" id="inputPlantSite">
      <option value="Syncrude Base Mine">Syncrude Base Mine</option>
      <option value="Syncrude Base Plant">Syncrude Base Plant</option>
      <option value="Syncrude Aurora Base Mine">Syncrude Aurora Base Mine</option>
      <option value="Syncrude Aurora Base Plant">Syncrude Aurora Base Plant</option>
      <option value="Suncor Base Mine">Suncor Base Mine</option>
      <option value="Suncor Base Plant">Suncor Base Plant</option>
      <option value="Suncor Firebag">Suncor Firebag</option>
      <option value="Albian Sands">Albian Sands</option>
      </select>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Route Number e.g. 1" name="inputRouteNumber" id="inputRouteNumber">
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Stop Number e.g. 1" name="inputStopNumber" id="inputStopNumber">
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Latitude" name="inputLatitude" id="inputLatitude">
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Longitude" name="inputLongitude" id="inputLongitude">
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Street Name" name="inputStreetName" id="inputStreetName">
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Arrival Time e.g. 6:00am" name="inputArrivalTime" id="inputArrivalTime">
        <select name="inputDayOfWeek" class="input-block-level" id="inputDayOfWeek">
          <option value="Weekday">Weekday</option>
          <option value="Weekend">Weekend</option>
          <option value="ADO">ADO</option>
        </select>
        <select name="inputDirectionOfBus" class="input-block-level" id="inputDirectionOfBus">
        <option value="Town to Site">Town To Site</option>
        <option value="Site To Town">Site To Town</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="inputWhatShift" id="inputWhatShift" class="input-block-level" placeholder="What Shift e.g. Day Night">
        <select name="markerVariable" class="input-block-level">
          <option value="addmarker" class="alert-success">Add Marker</option>
          <option value="updatemarker" class="alert-info">Update Marker</option>
          <option value="deletemarker" class="alert-error">Delete Marker</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" name="addmarker" id="submit_marker" class="btn btn-info btn-large">Create Marker</button>
  </form>
```

PHP File:

```
   <?php
require_once('./config.inc.php');

$plantsite = $_POST['inputPlantSite'];
$routenumber = $_POST['inputRouteNumber'];
$stopnumber = $_POST['inputStopNumber'];
$latitude = $_POST['inputLatitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['inputLongitude'];
$streetname = $_POST['inputStreetName'];
$markertitle = "Stop $stopnumber Route $routenumber";
$arrivaltime = $_POST['inputArrivalTime'];
$directionofbus = $_POST['inputDirectionOfBus'];
$whatshift = $_POST['inputWhatShift'];
$inputSearchSite = $_POST['inputSearchSite'];
$inputSearchRoute = $_POST['inputSearchRoute'];
$dayofweek = $_POST['inputDayOfWeek'];
$inputMarkerVariable = $_POST['markerVariable'];
$success = 0;

/* Connect to Database */
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf('Connect failed: %s\n', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT Latitude, Longitude, Title, Arrival_Time, Direction_Of_Bus, What_Shift FROM Routes")) {
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($gLatitude, $gLongitude, $gTitle, $gArrivalTime, $gDirectionOfBus, $gwhatShift);


}

if ($inputMarkerVariable == "addmarker") {
  /* Check fields */
  if ((!empty($stopnumber)) && (!empty($whatshift)) && (!empty($routenumber)) && (!empty($latitude))
      && (!empty($longitude)) && (!empty($streetname)) && (!empty($arrivaltime))) {

    /* Connect to the Database */

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    /* Get ready to query database */

    if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO Routes (Plant_Site, Route_Number, Stop_Number, Street_Name,
                                   Latitude, Longitude, Title, Arrival_Time, Day_Of_Week,
                                   Added_By, Direction_Of_Bus, What_Shift, Updated_At, Created_At)
                                   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW())")) {

      /* Bind Parameters */

      $stmt -> bind_param('ssssssssssss', $plantsite, $routenumber, $stopnumber, $streetname,
                          $latitude, $longitude, $markertitle,
                          $arrivaltime, $dayofweek, $sesh_email, $directionofbus, $whatshift);

      /* Exceute and send it to database */

      $stmt -> execute();

      $success = 1;
      json_encode(true);
      json_encode(false);

      $stmt -> close();


      if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT Latitude, Longitude, Title, Arrival_Time, Direction_Of_Bus, What_Shift FROM Routes")) {
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($gLatitude, $gLongitude, $gTitle, $gArrivalTime, $gDirectionOfBus, $gwhatShift);




}


    } else {
      printf('Couldnt make a connection');
    }
  } else { $alertmarker = "Not all fields are filled out"; }
}


if (isset($_POST['inputSortMarkers'])) {
    $mysqli -> mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    /* Get Ready to Sort Markers */

    if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT Latitude, Longitude, Title, Arrival_Time, Direction_Of_Bus, What_Shift FROM Routes WHERE Plant_Site = ? AND Route_Number = ?")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param('si', $inputSearchSite, $inputSearchRoute);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($gLatitude, $gLongitude, $gTitle, $gArrivalTime, $gDirectionOfBus, $gwhatShift);
        printf('Worked');
    }

}




?>
```

Comment: Is `alert (dataString);return false;` available in your script ? `return false` will terminate the execution of the function.

Comment: @SheikhHeera it is, but only for debugging, you can see every variable is not being loaded only the first one

Comment: I am not really sure what your issue is. What is the actual problem that you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `return false` in your code so code below that will not execute ever.

Also you can use `$('form').serialize();` to send datastring.

And use below code.

```
$("#submit_marker").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
```

above code will force `button` to execute only `click` event code.

Comment: Can you please see my script that is updated in the original post and tell me why it's not getting added to the database, keep in mind the Success alert is triggering, so does that mean it's a problem on the PHP side or?

Comment: @XCritics if its shows you successfully added marker then there might be error in server-side...but if your serverside script fail then i dont think it will alert success code..but can i see php code.

Comment: It's there in the body of the main post now

Comment: Any idea at all what the problem might be?

Comment: @XCritics try to return json_encode true or false...and set dataType : 'json' in ajax call

Comment: @XCritics in your php code...put it as echo json_encode(true); exit; where you feel script will return true and do it for false too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25643/discussion-between-xcritics-and-dipesh-parmar)

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding each variable being concatenated into dataString:

```
dataString = 'inputPlantSite=' + encodeURIComponent(inputPlantSite) + '&..=' + encodeURIComponent(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try serializing your information like this..

```
 var serialized = $(dataString).serialize(); 

 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "php/addmarker.php",
      data: serialized,
      success: function() {
        alert("Successfully added marker");
      }
```

The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements.

Comment: Did you checked this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231810/escaping-jquery-data-being-sent-via-post

Comment: `formselector` shown in that post is not same as `datastring` in your answer. Try it yourself... create a demo in jsfiddle.net and try to serialize `datastring`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.post('php/addmarker.php',{
    //param : value
    inputPlantSite : inputPlantSite,
    inputRouteNumber : inputRouteNumber,
    inputStopNumber : inputStopNumber,
    inputLatitude : inputLatitude,
    inputLongitude : inputLongitude,
    inputStreetName : inputStreetName,
    inputArrivalTime : inputArrivalTime,
    inputDayOfWeek : inputDayOfWeek,
    inputDirectionOfBus : inputDirectionOfBus,
    inputWhatShift : inputWhatShift,
    inputAddMarker : inputAddMarker,
    inputUpdateMarker : inputUpdateMarker,
    inputDeleteMarker : inputDeleteMarker
  },function(data){
    console.log(data);
    alert("Successfully added marker");
  });
```