# Why if include ''&amp'' in text area value JQUERY remove all textarea value data and empty data posted to database

Tags: php, jquery

Hi stackoverflow community i don't know what is wrong, I have two pages one is **index.php**
and another is **test.php** am using JQUERY to post data from index.php page to test.php page but when include "&amp" in textarea value, empty data posted to test.php. Below are my code.

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>


<!-----  This is my data that i type in the textarea=>'&amp <a href="http://www.example.com/example.php?test=test">This is a link</a>'  --> 






<div id="maya568mbad" class="">     
<div id="main"><textarea name="body" id='hiitest'  cols="20" rows="5" placeholder='Add  Reply'></textarea><input type="submit" class="msptd_584"  value="Reply" /></div></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function (e) {

$(document).on('click', '.msptd_584', function(d){
var maneno = $('#hiitest').val();
posted = 'msadhgstsmanu='+ maneno;


console.log(posted);//// up to here i get correct answer

$.ajax ({
      url: 'test.php',
      data: posted,
       type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,    
      success: function(data){

        console.log(data)/////The empty data returned here..!! means that the data sent to test.php is empty ;

        }
       
     });


 });

 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Second page **test.php**

```
<?php 

///dbcon Database PDO CONNECTION/////
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'databasename';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$port = "3306";
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;port=$port";
try {
       $dbcon= new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
////dbcon Database PDO CONNECTION  code Eding/////


$bodyfirst = (array_key_exists('msadhgstsmanu', $_POST) ? $_POST['msadhgstsmanu'] : "");

$email2 = 'my name';

$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO test (jina,mwisho)VALUES(:nani2e,:comm_body21)");
$stmt->execute(['nani2e'=>$bodyfirst,'comm_body21'=>$email2]);
```

this is my database table result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddXmB.png)

Comment: Try replacing &amp; with it's urlencoded value.  %26amp%3B

Comment: Can you try `data: { msadhgstsmanu: maneno },` instead, this way you don't need the additional character encoding, ans its simple to read

Comment: thank you @Scuzzy now working fine..!! but i want to know what is causes

Comment: When post data is encoded into a string, its done like `key1=data&key2=data2` if there is an ampersand in the text, you need to escape it so its not confused, jQuery will do this automatically when its an object, otherwise you have to use urlencoding functions on your value.

Comment: eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231810/escaping-jquery-data-being-sent-via-post

Comment: Scuzzy
Thank you very much..!! This issue took me a long time, I realized that if I write 1&2, it also becomes the same issue..!! thank you have a nice day..!! Welcome Tanzania

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the following changes:

index.php

```
$.ajax ({
      url: 'http://localhost/stackOverflow/test.php',
      data: {msadhgstsmanu:maneno},
       type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){

        console.log(data)/////The empty data returned here..!! means that the data sent to test.php is empty ;

        }

     });

 });
```

test.php

```
$bodyfirst = $_POST['msadhgstsmanu'];
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It means that if you use jQuery to post data as an object, it is the correct way than the other way...? @D. Dimopoulos

Comment: Using data as an object is a better way to post in ajax functions.